# How to evaluate a function at a point in Matlab?

Tags: function, math, matlab, evaluate

For example, if I have a function `f(x)=x^2`, how can I evaluate it at `x=2`?
I have tried employing the symbolic toolbox and using the following code in the Command Window:

```
syms x;
f = sym(x^2);
subs(f,x,2);
```

But I just get this error on the first line:
`Undefined function 'syms' for input arguments of type 'char'.`

I am completely new to Matlab and still working out the syntax, so I may have a syntactical error. However, I also have a Student trial edition, so I supposedly can't use the symbolic toolbox. Is there any way I can define `f(x)` and evaluate it at `x=2`?

Comment: Works fine for me, so it does indeed look like your missing the symbolic toolbox.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use anonymous functions:

```
>> f = @(x) x^2;
```

and then write

```
>> f(2)

ans =

     4
```

Answer (score 4):

Without the [Symbolic Math Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/symbolic/), you can still do something similar. One way to do it would be to define `x` as a vector of discrete values and calculate `f` over that:

```
x = 0:0.01:10; %// lower bound, step size, upper bound
f = x.^2;      %// use the element-wise power operator .^
y = f(x == 2); %// get the value for f where x is 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can simply define it in an .m file:  Eg In f.m:  `function [x] = f(x);x = x ^ 2;`

```
>> f(2)

ans =

     4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

> > syms x
> >
> > f = x^2
> >
> > subs(f,2)
> >
> > ans

4